# (16.04) How can I remotely control an Ubuntu desktop outside of its local network using another Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, remote-access

Tried Remmina (VNC) but only managed to do it on the local network.

Comment: Any desktop client/server should work provided you are forwarding the ports on your router and your ISP/Firewall/Antivirus isn't blocking them. I personally have used Chrome Remote Desktop and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

SSH should work for you

> sudo apt install openssh-server

then, if you have ufw enabled, do `sudo ufw allow ssh`

now. you need to set up port forwarding to your computer from the router. then, do `curl icanhazip.com` to find your public IP address.

if you want to remotely access your computer from inside the same network, find your private IP address with either `iwconfig` or `ifconfig`.

when you are ready to access your computer remotely, go to the client (the computer you will be accessing from) and do install openssh-client

> sudo apt install openssh-client

now. FINALLY you can access your remote desktop by doing `ssh [username]@[IP]` replace [username] with the username of the user you want to access and [IP] with the public or private IP of the remote desktop.

--Good Luck!